# Retrieving MS SQL database size in culture independent format

Tags: sql, database, size

sp_helpdb returns strings like '50000.255 MB' in the db_size column.

These strings are culture-dependent; the above string will mean 2 different things in US and Germany (in the latter, the dot char is used as a group separator, similar to the comma in US).

Is there another method which returns a numeric value, culture-independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Use YourDB;
 SELECT SUM(Size / 128.0) As FileSize from sys.database_files;
```

This returns the size in MB as a numeric, you should be able to do what you like with it from there.

Note: size returns the number of 8KB pages in a given database file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible. The SP [sp_helpdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178568.aspx) uses [str](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) to convert the numeric size to `varchar` and there is nothing in the documentation (that I can find) that can make `str` use `,` instead of `.` as decimal symbol. Using [set language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) does not help.

Workaround as suggested by Martin in comment

```
select replace(str(sum(convert(dec(17,2),size)) / 128,10,2) +' MB', '.', ',') 
from sys.database_files
```

Comment: The OP could of course select from `dbo.sysfiles` themselves though which is all that `sp_helpdb` does (although actually that is deprecated in favour of `sys.database_files` anyway)